# is pos_hint incompatible with DragBehaviour in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The documentation offers [an example](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html) of how to use DragBehaviour which works as long as I use `pos` to indicate the place the widget, but not if I use `pos_hint`:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<DragLabel>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0

FloatLayout:
    DragLabel:

        ##################################
        ##### Comment this line and works!
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y':0.5}


        size_hint: 0.25, 0.2
        text: 'Drag me'
'''

class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    pass
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
TestApp().run()
```

How can I use `pos_hint` with `DragBehaviour`? Are they incompatible because of the way Kivy binds properties?

Answer (score 0):

According to "Creating Apps In Kivy" by Dusty Phillips:

> The Layout sets `pos` based on the `pos_hint`; they aren't strictly independent values. The same can be said for `size_hint`, which is why layouts require you to explicitly set `size_hint` to `None` if you want to manipulate the `size` directly.

In other words, both the `FloatLayout` and the `DragBehavior` want to set the widget's `pos`, and because the layout gets the last go at it, it ends up winning. But `FloatLayout` sets the `pos` based on the `pos_hint`, and doesn't try to set it if the latter is uninitialized. Likewise, if you were to try to set the `size`, `FloatLayout` would use its default `size_hint` of `(1,1)` to overrule you, unless you first explicitly set `size_hint` to `(None,None)`.